# How to make Qt tear-off menu appear in alt-tab navigation?

Tags: python, qt, menu, pyqt4

Qt tear-off menus don't seem to appear in Alt-tab task switcher navigation, presumably because they are not top-level widgets.  That means that as soon as the torn-off menu window is obscured by another window, it is impossible for the user to ever see it again.

Here is an example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
QtGui.QApplication.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
w = QtGui.QMainWindow(parent=None)
menu = w.menuBar().addMenu("Menu")
menu.setTearOffEnabled(True)

quit_action = QtGui.QAction("&Quit", w, triggered=QtGui.qApp.quit)
menu.addAction(quit_action)

w.show()
app.exec_()
```

To reproduce the problem:

- Run the program
- Open the menu labelled "Menu"
- Click on the dotted line to "tear off" the menu
- Close the main window
- Use Alt-Tab to switch to a different window that completely obscures the torn-off menu
- At this point, there is no way to find the torn-off menu window

I've only tried to reproduce the problem on Linux in both GNOME 2 and GNOME Shell, but I'm assuming it happens on all systems.

How can I make the torn-off menu window appear in the Alt-tab navigation?

Comment: Would a more intuitive behaviour be for it to appear always on top?

Comment: you normally would not want it to appear in the alt-tab list but just bring the window to the front when your app gets focus. that way if the user switches to another app and the torn off window goes behind, it will come back to top when he tabs back to your app. It might not be too nice if you have 10 torn off windows and they all appear as individual alt-tab targets

Comment: In fact this particular app uses a QSystemTrayIcon, so there is no such other window.  I don't show that in the question just because the code I gave is shorter -- maybe a mistake!

Comment: Re always on top: no, I think that would be surprising, because the window looks the same as any other window.  Why would it behave differently (in an application that may have no other top-level windows, recall)?